# Converting output in multiple rows to single row with separate column using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a output like below which I wish to convert it to single row (without space)

```
 vol sysvol : 25654
 vol sysvol : 39%
 vol sysvol : 820928KB
 vol vol01 : 502
 vol vol01 : 0%
 vol vol01 : 16064KB
 vol vol02 : 65491
 vol vol02 : 99%
 vol vol02 : 2095712KB
 DB : 91647
 DB : 46%
 DB : 2932704KB
```

I used command below

```
awk 'NR%3{printf "%s,",$0;next;}1'
```

but it returns me output like

```
 vol sysvol : 25654 , vol sysvol : 39% , vol sysvol : 820928KB
 vol vol01 : 502 , vol vol01 : 0% , vol vol01 : 16064KB
 vol vol02 : 65491 , vol vol02 : 99% , vol vol02 : 2095712KB
 DB : 91647 , DB : 46% , DB : 2932704KB
```

Where as I wish to have output like

```
vol sysvol: 25654 , 39%  , 820928KB
vol vol01 : 502 , 0% , 16064KB
vol vol02 : 65491 ,  99% ,  2095712KB
DB : 91647 , 46% ,  2932704KB
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F: -v OFS=, '{if (NR%3==1) printf "%s : %s",$1,$2 OFS;
                   else printf "%s", $2 (NR%3?OFS:ORS)}' file  

vol sysvol  :  25654, 39%, 820928KB                     
vol vol01  :  502, 0%, 16064KB                                     
vol vol02  :  65491, 99%, 2095712KB                             
DB  :  91647, 46%, 2932704KB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="," }
$1 != prev { if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$0; prev=$1; next }
{ rec = rec OFS $2 }
END { print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
 vol sysvol : 25654 , 39% , 820928KB
 vol vol01 : 502 , 0% , 16064KB
 vol vol02 : 65491 , 99% , 2095712KB
 DB : 91647 , 46% , 2932704KB
```